# Phase Diagram in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hello Everyone by example below

I try to make a phase diagram with code

This is the code and data produced

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
x = np.array([a[0] for a in data[1:]])
y = np.array([a[1] for a in data[1:]])
  #x=np.array([0,30,60,90,120,150])
  #y=np.array([20,10,5,2.5,1.25,0.625])
  #define x as 200 equally spaced values between the min and max of original x
plt.tick_params(
      axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
      which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
      bottom=False,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
      top=False,         # ticks along the top edge are off
      labelbottom=True) 
plt.tick_params(
      axis='y',          # changes apply to the x-axis
      which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
      left=False,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
      top=False,         # ticks along the top edge are off
      labelbottom=True) 

#plt.grid(color = 'black', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 0.5)

plt.plot(x,y, linestyle='-',color='black')

#x1 = [0,40,2,0]
#y2 = [-24,2,10,2]
#plt.fill_betweenx([0, 60], [21., 20.2],[-20,10], facecolor="black", alpha=0.8)
#plt.fill_between(x1,y2)
plt.fill_between(x,y, np.vstack([y]).min(0).clip(min=120),color='yellow',alpha=.3)
plt.fill_between(x,-40, np.vstack([y]).min(0).clip(min=-23),color='blue',alpha=.3)
plt.fill_between(x,y, np.vstack([x]).min(0).clip(max=0),color='green',alpha=.3)

#plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 25, 5))
#plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 50, 100))
plt.xlabel("NaCl em  water %(m/v)")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura / C")
plt.xticks([0,50,100])
plt.ylim([-40,120])
filename = "decai.png"
plt.savefig(filename)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This command makes the area fill

```
plt.fill_between(x,y, np.vstack([y]).min(0).clip(min=120),color='yellow',alpha=.3)
```

How can I make an area in the diagram color division in axis zero, and limit blue in 23.2. This graph example here

[image]

Comment: What about just `plt.fill_between(x,y,120,color='yellow',alpha=.3)`?  For the green it is a bit hard to guess what you want, maybe `plt.fill_between(x,np.minimum(y,0),0,color='green',alpha=.3)`? (The `y` of the test-data is all positive, so not very interesting when trying to show the part below `0`)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for explanation, my finally graph is draw area after black line.  This link picture above show finally driagram phase in area for show different phases. More difficult is limit draw area graph