# Creating a phase-type plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for this kind of plot but I really don't know what it is called in English. (I am not a native English speaker.)

[image]

After searching, I only found this SO [phase question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585272/phase-diagram-in-matplotlib) but is not clear to me. Can someone direct me on how to start creating this plot or maybe tell me what the correct name is for it?

Comment: I don't know how this plot would be called in your field of study. For matplotlib it are just filled polygons. See e.g. [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill.html).

Comment: Something related would be a [voronoi diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515554/colorize-voronoi-diagram)

Comment: This can probably be created using `plt.fill_between` as @JohanC suggested in the SO question you linked in your post. Some parts might take a little trickery to do.

Comment: That is a "phase diagram" in English, Orlando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching with some of the links provided above, I found out that plotting polygons is what i need.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 polygon1 = Polygon([(-26.7243,-14.7423), (-26.7243,-30.0000), 
 (-40.0000,-30.0000),(-40.0000,-28.0181)], color='#660066', label='Fe')
 polygon2 = Polygon([(-18.1347,-0.4263), (-16.6048,1.6135), (-16.6048,-30.0000), 
 (-26.7243,-30.0000),(-26.7243,-14.7423),(-18.1347,-0.4263)], color='#b6fcd5', 
 label='Fe3O4')
 polygon3 = Polygon([(-18.1347,-0.4263), (-26.7243,-14.7423), 
 (-40.0000,-28.0181),(-40.0000,-22.2917),(-18.1347,-0.4263)], color='#ff7f50', 
 label='FeS')
 polygon4 = Polygon([(0.0000,-20.2615), (0.0000,-30.0000), (-16.6048,-30.0000), 
 (-16.6048,1.6135),(-16.5517,1.6865),(-6.0517,-0.9385),(0.0000,-3.9643)], 
  color='#ffb6c1', label='Fe2O3')
 polygon5 = Polygon([(-14.2390,10.0000), (-14.5829,7.5927), (-16.5517,1.6865), 
 (-16.6048,1.6135),(-18.1347,-0.4263),(-40.0000,-22.2917),(-40.0000,10.0000)], 
 color='#c6e2ff', label='FeS2')
 polygon6 = Polygon([(-6.0517,-0.9385), (-16.5517,1.6865), (-14.5829,7.5927), 
 (-6.0517,-0.9385)], color='#d3ffce', label='FeSO4')
 polygon7 = Polygon([(0.0000,-3.9643), (-6.0517,-0.9385), (-14.5829,7.5927), 
 (-14.2390,10.0000),(0.0000,10.0000)], color='#8a2be2', label='Fe2(SO4)3')
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

 ax.add_patch(polygon1)
 ax.add_patch(polygon2)
 ax.add_patch(polygon3)
 ax.add_patch(polygon4)
 ax.add_patch(polygon5)
 ax.add_patch(polygon6)
 ax.add_patch(polygon7)
 plt.ylim(-30,10)
 plt.xlim(-40,0)
 plt.legend(loc='best')
 plt.show()
```

which yields this:
[image]

I will add the annotations later. Thanks for your comments.